# When I immerse glass tube (open from both ends) in water and closes upper end by thumb, then why after lifting tube, the water keeps inside the tube?

Tags: fluid-statics

I was solving a physics problem which uses this concept, and i cannot understand why this happens, it'll be of great help if you can help me.

Answer (score 2):

For the water to fall freely out the bottom of the tube requires that air enter the tube as the water exits the same tube at the same time: the air and water have to move past each other, within the confines of the tube. This is called *two-phase flow*.

Two-phase flow requires the *meniscus* (the surface boundary between the air and the water) to get stretched and curved so that the air and water can manage to squeeze by each other within that confined space.

Because the meniscus exhibits a property called *surface tension*, it resists being stretched and bent, just as if it were an elastic rubber membrane, and would rather form a smooth boundary between the water in the tube and the air outside the tube. It is this surface tension force which holds the water column up against gravity and prevents air from intruding.

This "locking" effect depends strongly on the diameter of the tube: small tubes are dominated by surface tension, and the water remains trapped inside the tube (i.e., two-phase flow cannot be established). Larger tubes are dominated by gravity, and surface tension effects are overcome and the water gurgles out the bottom of the tube as air bubbles into the tube.

You can demonstrate this interplay of forces in the kitchen, using a simple device called a *baster*. This is a clear plastic tube with a restricted snoot on one end and a rubber squeeze bulb on the other (chemists call this a *pipettor*).

To slurp up and remove some tasty juices from a roasting pan fresh from the oven, you squeeze the bulb, insert the snoot into the tasty juices, and release the bulb to create a suction inside the baster. The tasty juices will then be drawn up into the baster tube. Now here comes the fun part:

If the designers of the baster understand *physics*, they will narrow down the snoot diameter enough so that surface tension wins the battle against gravity and when you withdraw the snoot from the tasty juices, *the juices will be retained inside the baster*. No two-phase flow in a properly-designed baster!

If the designers of the baster do *not* understand physics, they will fail to neck down the snoot diameter enough and as soon as you withdraw the snoot tip from the remaining tasty juices, they will spontaneously gurgle right out the bottom of the snoot tip and run back into the roasting pan (if you are lucky) or onto the floor (if you are not). Because two-phase flow is supported within the snoot, *carnage and mayhem in the kitchen* may well be the result as those tasty juices slosh out onto the floor, never to form the basis of a tasty sauce.

Comment: In my experience with basters, the fact that tasty juices are HOT causes the air inside the baster to get hot  and raise the internal pressure. The result is that the tasty juices exit the baster annoyingly rapidly even when the snoot is small.

Comment: @mikestone, that is true, but wilt care you can unsqueeze the baster bulb in just such a manner as to accomodate the volumetric expansion of the air remaining inside the baster as you slurp. Learning this skill in the kitchen will amaze and entertain your friends, while baffling and confusing your enemies.

Comment: @ niels nielsen I have long tried to master this art, but sadly have  always failed :(.

Comment: @mikestone, the ultra-top secret trick for *real hip dudes only* is to withdraw the snoot from the tasty juice *before the bulb is fully relaxed* so as to draw up some air into the baster, and then hold the snoot tip over the roasting pan so that your spectators cannot observe the snoot tip as it pees a little. Then, when everything has settled into equilibrium, you produce the baster with a flourish and exclaim "wa LAH!" as your audience applauds.

Comment: @ niels nielsen. I bow to the master.